# symfony jq_link_to_remote using POST fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony1

I'm trying to use a simple ajax link:

```
jq_link_to_remote('Click me!', array(  'update' => 'myDiv',
                                       'url'    => 'module/action?id='.$user->getId(),
                                       'method' => 'post' ));
```

The action is really simple:

```
public function executeAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    return $this->renderText('test');
}
```

When I press the link nothing happens.  If I change the 'method' to 'get' it works as expected - How can that be?

Comment: Can you also include the action code that this posts to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
requirements:
    sf_method: [get, post]
```

to the module/action route and it works now :)

thanks for the help Tom!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've played with this plugin, but a quick look in the docs says POST is default and only GET would need to be declared. So my first guess would be that declaring the method as post breaks it. In other words, remove the method declaration altogether to make it a POST.

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/11-Ajax-Integration#chapter_11_sub_determining_the_ajax_request_method

Comment: actually, my first try was without the method attribute. I tried it again now and it still doesn't work.. any other ideas?

Comment: What does the HTML source look like that gets rendered as on the page by that jq_link_to_remote function?